# Ubuntu 13.04 'brightness and lock' not working!

Tags: 13.04, brightness

I am unable to change the brightness of my Acer Aspire V3-571-6850 laptop.

My system details are:

Memory: 7.6 GiB
Processor: Intel Core i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50Ghz * 4
Graphics: Intel Ivybridge Mobile
OS type: 64-bit
Disk: 730.0GB

Comment: please provide system details, in particular the graphics card you are using, and whether you have installed the graphics drivers.

Comment: I have not installed any drivers

Comment: please open a terminal (ctrl+alt+t) and post the output of `lspci | grep VGA`.

Comment: here is the output: http://i.imgur.com/ETuH8nO.png

Answer (score 1):

You can change brightness using command line as follows:

- Open Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type

  ```
  $ ls /sys/class/backlight/
  ```
- You will get some output like `intel_backlight  sony`. If you have intel_backlight as one of the outputs, it means that you have Intel Graphic driver installed.
- To know the maximum brightness supported by your screen, type

  ```
  $ cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness
  ```

  Here, **intel_backlight** can be replaced by your graphic driver folder name.
- To change the brightness to your desired level, type

  ```
  $ echo 3000 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
  ```

  where 3000 can be replaced by your desired brightness level, upto your maximum screen brightness number.

For more information, refer to this backlight [Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight#ACPI).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install proprietary drivers for your graphics card.

1. Go to the gear icon in the top right corner of your screen and
   select "System Settings..."
2. Select "Software & Updates"
3. On the "Additional Drivers" tab, select a proprietary graphics driver (I suggest starting with the *-updates one, with the highest driver number, as it tends to be the most recent and up to date. For example, see image below for my nvidia card.)
4. Once it's installed you will need to reboot your computer for the settings to take effect.

[image]

[EDIT: additional information on Intel Graphics]

Intel graphics drivers for Ubuntu 13.04 have recently been packaged and released by Intel in an Ubuntu installer:

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-linux-graphics-installer-version-1.0.1

1. Download the appropriate .deb file for your system architecture ([32 bit](https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/13.04/main/pool/13.04/i/intel-linux-graphics-installer/intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.1_i386.deb) or [64 bit](https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/13.04/main/pool/13.04/i/intel-linux-graphics-installer/intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.1_amd64.deb))
2. Get the intel repository key so the packages will be trusted:

   `wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg -O - | \`

   `sudo apt-key add -`

   `wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-2 -O - | \`

   `sudo apt-key add -`
3. Install the package (.deb) you downloaded by opening it in Software Centre

*I can't vouch for how well they work, since I don't have an Intel graphics card, so just be sure you follow the instructions and be aware of any "Known Issues" that are presented on the package website.*

Comment: but this is what shows up when i click on 'additional drivers' in the third step. i.imgur.com/Crzo9ar.png

Comment: I see you added more info to your question and that your using intel graphics. I'll post more in the comments to your original question.

Comment: @fidgetyphi updated answer for intel graphics

Comment: and this is the 'failure message' that I get when I try to install the driver with the above mentioned 'Intel Driver Manager' software: i.imgur.com/NRcnlCL.png

Comment: that's a 404 error which means you weren't connected to internet when installing or their server was down. I suggest trying again. Hopefully it was just a temporary glitch.